# SSIS Custom Transforms - what is MappedColumnID

Tags: ssis

SSIS developer documentation is notoriously terse, and I've scoured Google looking for an answer on this...

What is the **MappedColumnID** property (available on input, output and external metadata columns) all about? It doesn't *appear* to do anything useful.

Perhaps to rephrase the question... how do I achieve mappings between meta data columns and input / output columns? I know about the ExternalMetaDataColumnID property... but then how/where does MappedColumnID come into play?

Moreover, components like the OLEDB destination have a column mapping editor which appears in both the component UI as well as in the advanced editor. How is this achieved?

Comment: Charming, a randomly undocumented property.  Not needed, perhaps, but it sure looks like it *might* be useful when troubleshooting the ubiquitous LineageID errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MappedColumnID is just an alternative way of identifying the columns instead of using there names.
From MSDN

> [The use of these properties is not required. These properties provide an easier way for developers to associate related columns, such as input and output columns, in custom data flow components.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.idtsexternalmetadatacolumn100.mappedcolumnid.aspx)